# How to minimize Math calls? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, math

I'm doing a [Codewars challenge](http://www.codewars.com/kata/53d8aea2e584dd9e67000ae6/train/javascript) in which I have to create a function with the parameters a, b & c corresponding to the quadratic equation ax^2 + bx + c = 0 and solve for x. The goal is not only to solve for x, but to minimize the number of spendy Math.sqrt calls. (You also have to return an array with the unique solution(s)).

I came up with a solution:

```
function solveQuadratic(a, b, c) {
  if ((4*a*c > b*b) || ((a === 0) && (b === 0))) { return undefined;}
  else if (a === 0) {return [-c/b];}
  else {
   var xVals = [];
   var sqrt = Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c);
   xVals.push((-b - sqrt)/2*a);
   xVals.push((-b + sqrt)/2*a);
   if (xVals[0] === xVals[1]) {xVals.pop();}
   return xVals;
  }
}
```

I got the error message:

> You passed the tests using 6 Math.sqrt calls.
>   You should be able to pass these tests with 4 Math.sqrt calls or less.

I thought storing the result of the square root part of the expression in a variable (sqrt) would prevent it from being called more than that one time to evaluate the expression and assign a value to the variable. But that's not the case.

So I have a couple of questions:

- Is there a way to store a (static) value so that it doesn't need to be reevaluated any time it's used in your code?
- Is there something obvious I'm missing from this solution besides the fact that it's making too many Math.sqrt calls?

Comment: Your code is making **one** call to `Math.sqrt()` ...

Comment: A _static_ value doesn’t get “re-evaluated”, that doesn’t make any sense. If it needs evaluating, then it is not a static value in the first place.

Comment: You appear to be making exactly one `Math.sqrt` call. Your subsequent references to the variable `sqrt` do not invoke the function. Does this code exist within a larger context that might account for the other 5 calls?

Comment: No, that's the complete code I'm submitting.

Comment: Are you calling this function six times with your test cases?

Comment: Does the test call the function multiple times? It sounds like it's asking you to solve 6 equations, and some of them have the same same coefficients.

Comment: That test (website) is HORRIBLE. I went to the website, they are very cryptic about it. They indeed say exactly what OP says here, and you have to _guess_ what they want. They should just say it up front! Is the subject of the test to _guess_ caching might help? That's devious - in a bad way.

Comment: @Mörre yes I found that the problem quality there is generally pretty low.

Comment: Please note `*` and `/` have equal precedence in JavaScript; you have to enclose `2*a` in parentheses, or your results will be wrong (unless of course _a_ happens to be one all the time).

Comment: It's a UGC site for challenges & the best I've seen at throwing a lot of fun/interesting challenges (how else to practice?), but because there isn't a rigorous editorial review, bugs appear.

Comment: @jfriend00 and Barmar: No. When I submitted, it had actually run through about 16 cases successfully before I got that error msg, so it can't be adding up the individual calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a case for when `c` is zero:

```
....
var sqrt = c==0?Math.abs(b):Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c);
....
```

**[Edit]**

Also, to pass all the tests, your solution needs parenthesis when dividing here:

```
xVals.push((-b - sqrt)/(2*a));
xVals.push((-b + sqrt)/(2*a));
```

Comment: OPs code with this modification does NOT pass the tests. Just go to the website OP links - you can just paste the code and click "Submit", it's very quick. I got a failure pasting OPs code with this one-line modification.

Comment: I did, but it does not pass for another reason. With my changes, the "6 Math.sqrt" calls issue is solved. Actually it says: `You passed the tests using 4 Math.sqrt calls.` but it fails for something else.

Comment: Fair enough, that's true.

Comment: Oh, never mind my earlier remark that you need to take the absolute value of _b_. The worst that could happen is that the two solutions will trade places; the result is the same.

Comment: @Joanvo: With these two modifications, it worked! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) . Use a closure to keep a static list of values used so you don't call `Math.sqrt` for values you've already calculated

```
var cachingSqrt = (function() {
    var inputs = {};
    return function(val) {
        if (inputs.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
            return inputs[val];
        } else {
            return inputs[val] = Math.sqrt(val);
        }
    }
})();
```

A generalization of this process would be

```
function createCachedResults(fn, scope) {
    var inputs = {};
    return function(val) {
        if (inputs.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
            return inputs[val];
        } else {
            return inputs[val] = fn.call(scope, val);
        }
    }
}

cachingSqrt  = createCachedResults(Math.sqrt, Math);
```

And you could use it like

```
var cachingSquareRoot = createCachedResults(Math.sqrt, Math);
function solveQuadratic(a, b, c) {
    if ((4*a*c > b*b) || ((a === 0) && (b === 0))) { 
        return undefined;
    }
    else if (a === 0) {
         return [-c/b];
    } else {
        var xVals = [];
        var sqrt = cachingSquareRoot(b*b - 4*a*c);
        xVals.push((-b - sqrt)/2*a);
        xVals.push((-b + sqrt)/2*a);
        if (xVals[0] === xVals[1]) { 
            xVals.pop();
        }
        return xVals;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a form of caching.  How would you integrate this into the OP's equation to solve their problem?

Comment: @jfriend00 Just use `sqrt` instead of `Math.sqrt()`?

Comment: Warning: this conflicts with his local variable `sqrt`.

Comment: This assumes that values of `a`, `b` and `c` are repeated between calls so that caching will offer a benefit.  The OP's question is not clear on whether this is the case or not.

Comment: @jfriend Since the OP is only calling it once in the code displayed, I assumed it must be being called with the same values.

Comment: The OP isn't calling it at all in the displayed code so it's unclear how `Math.sqrt()` gets called 6 times to start with.  That part of the OP's question is unclear.  You have one guess as to what's going on.  I'm just saying that it's a guess - maybe right or maybe something else is going on.  Can't really tell.  The question is unclear.

Comment: @jfriend00: It's likely the problem. I modified the OP's code to include some form of caching, submitted the code and it passed with "3 calls to Math.sqrt". But you are right, the question is not very specific about that and the test failure message is bad.

Comment: I guess a combination of caching with [Ruud's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27786480/227299) would be quite an improvement

Comment: @JuanMendes You could/should just test your result on the website OP links to. You can just copy/paste and click "Submit", it's fast and pain free - and your code does not work (doing just copy&paste) :)

Comment: @JuanMendes Thank you, Juan - memoization is a (useful) new concept you introduced to me. :)

Comment: It turns out I don't think this is the intended solution.  The solution comes from eliminating calls to `Math.sqrt(x)` when `x === 0` and when `x === b^2` since the sqrt is already known in those cases.  The actual code to do this is described in my answer.

Comment: @jfriend. Yes, it's a combination of Ruud's and Joanvo's solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to avoid `Math.sqrt(x)` when `x === 0` and when `x === b^2` since the answer is already known.  These two situations occur when `b^2 === 4ac` and when `4ac === 0`, so the code needs to short circuit those two cases to avoid the extra `Math.sqrt()` calls.

So, all the special cases are:

- When `b^2 - 4ac < 0` or `a === 0 && b === 0` which make the answer `undefined`.
- When `a === 0` (in which case the equation is linear, not quadratic) so the answer is `-c / b`.
- When `c === 0` which makes `4ac === 0` so it's just `-b / a` and `0`.
- When `b^2 - 4ac === 0` in which case the answer is just `-b / (2 * a)`

Using a combination of Ruud's suggestion and a fixed version of Joanvo's suggestion, it will pass with only 4 `Math.sqrt()` calls with this:

```
function solveQuadratic(a, b, c) {
    var delta = (b * b) - (4 * a * c), sqrt;
    if ((delta < 0) || ((a === 0) && (b === 0))) {
        return undefined;
    } else if (a === 0) {
        return [-c / b];
    } else if (c === 0) {
        return b === 0 ? [0] : [-b / a, 0];
    } else if (delta == 0) {
        return [-b / (2 * a)];
    } else {
        sqrt = Math.sqrt(delta);
        return [(-b - sqrt) / (2 * a), (-b + sqrt) / (2 * a)];
    }
}
```

---

Here's a version that builds on the above version and adds the cache from Juan's answer.  In the initial standard test, this reports only one `Math.sqrt()` operation.

```
function solveQuadratic(a, b, c) {
    var delta = (b * b) - (4 * a * c), sqrt;
    if ((delta < 0) || ((a === 0) && (b === 0))) {
        return undefined;
    } else if (a === 0) {
        return [-c / b];
    } else if (c === 0) {
        return b === 0 ? [0] : [-b / a, 0];
    } else if (delta == 0) {
        return [-b / (2 * a)];
    } else {
        sqrt = sqrt2(delta);
        return [(-b - sqrt) / (2 * a), (-b + sqrt) / (2 * a)];
    }
}

var sqrt2 = (function() {
    var cache = {0:0, 1:1, 4:2, 9:3};
    return function(x) {
        if (cache.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            return cache[x];
        } else {
            var result = Math.sqrt(x);
            cache[x] = result;
            return result;
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Nice write-up. The pop has become redundant and can be removed; you know the two roots are not equal because delta is never zero in that branch.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a shortcut for cases where the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) is zero.

```
...
else if (b*b == 4*a*c) return [-b / (2*a)];
...
```

Comment: OPs code with this modification does NOT pass the tests. Just go to the website OP links - you can just paste the code and click "Submit", it's very quick. I got a failure pasting OPs code with this one-line modification. Of course, OP only asked about the sqrt issue...

Comment: @Mörre: You are right, I forgot the brackets around the result. I fixed my answer.

Comment: This is only part of the answer.  It eliminates one `Math.sqrt()` call, but there's still another one to be eliminated.

Comment: @jfriend00: The standard tests are a bit meager; `1*x^2 + 0*x + 0 = 0` is the _only_ test case with a zero discriminant, but because C = 0 there, the same test is covered by joanvo's solution. In the random tests, my solution might save a few calls, but that does not count for passing the assignment. Joanvo's solution deserves the upvotes.